# Output Issue with FreeBusy for Outlook using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, office-automation

When I use the below code, the response is `11111001111100111110011111000` and `29`. Which doesn't make sense because there are only 24 hours in a day. Is there something I am missing?

Also, is it possible to dynamically do this over a date range?

```
import win32com.client
from datetime import datetime

query_date = datetime(2022, 4, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0)

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
user = namespace.CreateRecipient("user@domain.com")
schedule = user.FreeBusy(query_date, 60 * 24)
print(schedule)
print(len(schedule))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for `60*24=1440` minutes per character, which means each character corresponds to the whole day. If you want one hour per character, pass `60`.

Comment: Could you explain this concept a little further. Just getting back into python and uncertain by your response. When I change the value to 60, it returns a string with 696 characters. From my understanding, I thought this would return 24 characters, a 0 reflecting free, and 1 reflecting busy, is that not accurate?

Comment: FreeBusy returns about one month worth of data (29 days as you noticed). The second parameter is MinutesPerChar. If you pass 60, each char corresponds to 60 minutes (1 hour), If you pass 60*24=1440, you get one day per char. So it all depends on how much detail you want FreeBusy to return.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The following code returns a string of free/busy information with one character for each day:

```
schedule = user.FreeBusy(query_date, 60 * 24)
```

And the following code returns a string of free/busy information with one character for each hour (complete format):

```
schedule = user.FreeBusy(query_date, 60, true)
```

See [Recipient.FreeBusy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.freebusy) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can confirm this is correct. I am not able to upvote yet due to my status however.